# My deal method will not work. Help please?

Tags: java, arraylist

So i am creating a Card game and have been working using a template for my computer science class. However, there is no answer key to check and make sure that what im doing is correct. So the problem is that im trying to use an arraylist and deal a card and im unsure of how to resolve deal. I am new to Java so any help would be greatly appreciated. Below is my code:

```
public class Deck {

    /**
     * cards contains all the cards in the deck.
     */
    private List<Card> cards;

    /**
     * size is the number of not-yet-dealt cards.
     * Cards are dealt from the top (highest index) down.
     * The next card to be dealt is at size - 1.
     */
    private int size;



    /**
     * Creates a new <code>Deck</code> instance.<BR>
     * It pairs each element of ranks with each element of suits,
     * and produces one of the corresponding card.
     * @param ranks is an array containing all of the card ranks.
     * @param suits is an array containing all of the card suits.
     * @param values is an array containing all of the card point values.
     */
    public Deck(String[] ranks, String[] suits, int[] values) {
        ArrayList<Card> deck = new ArrayList<Card>();
        for(int a = 0; a<=ranks.length; a++){
            for(int b=0; b<=suits.length;b++){
                for(int c=0; c<=values.length; c++){
                    deck.add(new Card(ranks[a],suits[b],c));
                }
            }

        }
    }


    /**
     * Determines if this deck is empty (no undealt cards).
     * @return true if this deck is empty, false otherwise.
     */
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        if(size==0){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Accesses the number of undealt cards in this deck.
     * @return the number of undealt cards in this deck.
     */
    public int size() {
     return size;
    }
    /**
     * Randomly permute the given collection of cards
     * and reset the size to represent the entire deck.
     */
    public void shuffle() {
        /* *** TO BE IMPLEMENTED IN ACTIVITY 4 *** */
    }

    /**
     * Deals a card from this deck.
     * @return the card just dealt, or null if all the cards have been
     *         previously dealt.
     */
    public Card deal() {
        while(size>0){
            for(int i = 0;i<=size;i++){
                return deck[i];//This cannot be resolved to the deck arraylist above
                cards.remove(0);

            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Generates and returns a string representation of this deck.
     * @return a string representation of this deck.
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String rtn = "size = " + size + "\nUndealt cards: \n";

        for (int k = size - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
            rtn = rtn + cards.get(k);
            if (k != 0) {
                rtn = rtn + ", ";
            }
            if ((size - k) % 2 == 0) {
                // Insert carriage returns so entire deck is visible on console.
                rtn = rtn + "\n";
            }
        }

        rtn = rtn + "\nDealt cards: \n";
        for (int k = cards.size() - 1; k >= size; k--) {
            rtn = rtn + cards.get(k);
            if (k != size) {
                rtn = rtn + ", ";
            }
            if ((k - cards.size()) % 2 == 0) {
                // Insert carriage returns so entire deck is visible on console.
                rtn = rtn + "\n";
            }
        }

        rtn = rtn + "\n";
        return rtn;
    }
}
```

Comment: missing language tag. also you need to spend time debugging it and identifying where the problem could be.

Answer (score 0):

Despite that I have not quite understand your question yet this could probably help you:

One problem I have detected is the visibility of your `ArrayList<Card> deck`:

```
public Deck(String[] ranks, String[] suits, int[] values) {
    ArrayList<Card> deck = new ArrayList<Card>();
    ...
}
```

Since you only declare the `ArrayList` within the constructor you can't access the list from outside.

So just make the list **global** like your `List<Card> cards`. Then you can access it from your `deal()` method and your `Deck()` constructor.

Here you go:

```
public class Deck {

    private List<Card> cards;
    private int size;
    private List<Card> deck;

    public Deck(String[] ranks, String[] suits, int[] values) {
        deck = new ArrayList<Card>();
        for(int a = 0; a<=ranks.length; a++) {
            for(int b=0; b<=suits.length;b++) {
                for(int c=0; c<=values.length; c++) {
                    deck.add(new Card(ranks[a],suits[b],c));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```